# Dbplyr: combine two tables and add the to the result to the database without loading them in memory

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

Please have a look at the simple script at the end of the post.
I have a database containing two tables which I combine using union_all.
Is there a way to add the result to the database without collecting the data i.e. loading them into memory?
Many thanks!

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI) # main DB interface
library(dbplyr) # dplyr back-end for DBs
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dbplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     ident, sql
library(RSQLite)


##create the databases

df1 <- tibble(x=1:20,y=rep(c("a", "b"), 10))


df2 <- tibble(x=101:120,y=rep(c("d", "e"), 10))




con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db.sqlite")

dbWriteTable(con,"mydata1",df1, overwrite=T)
dbWriteTable(con,"mydata2",df2, overwrite=T)

dbDisconnect(con) # closes our DB connection


con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db.sqlite")

mydb1 <- tbl(con, "mydata1")
mydb2 <- tbl(con, "mydata2")


mydb12 <- union_all(mydb1,mydb2)

#is there a way to add the union of mydb1 and mydb2 to the database without explicitly collecting the data?
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Simply run `UNION ALL` in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're dealing with SQL, just use SQL.

```r
collect(mydb1) %>%
  nrow()
# [1] 20
DBI::dbExecute(con, "insert into mydata1 select * from mydata2")
# [1] 20
collect(mydb1) %>%
  nrow()
# [1] 40
collect(mydb1) %>%
  tail()
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#       x y    
#   <int> <chr>
# 1   115 d    
# 2   116 e    
# 3   117 d    
# 4   118 e    
# 5   119 d    
# 6   120 e
```

If you want the combined data in a new table, then here's an alternative.

```r
DBI::dbExecute(con, "
  create table mydata12 as
    select * from mydata2 union all select * from mydata1")
```

Comment: Thanks. About your suggestion to create a new table with the combined data (it is what I am really after): does it require to load the data in memory? I will be working with large tables and I absolutely need to avoid that. I believe I should be safe since it is sql that we are talking about, but can you confirm that?

Comment: It does not load the data into R; the only data returned to R on the first `dbExecute` command is `20`, an integer, the number of rows affected by that command; in the second (create) call, it returns an integer again (though not the number of rows returned). Neither returns a frame, neither loads the combined dataset into R.

Comment: I can't help but wonder, are you really dealing with "large tables" in SQLite? While I know it can deal with large data, there may be a point where it would make sense for you to work with more of a clustered DBMS.

Comment: Well,  maybe gigabytes if data is.not big data these.days, bit it is for.my.seasoned workstation 

Comment: The discussion of DBMS/size aside, does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for a pure dbplyr solution, but yours works and reminds me it is time to learn some sql for real.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but unfortunately I don't know if/how to do that in `dbplyr`-native verbs.